# Вывод в задаче о золотой горе

Tags: c++, вывод, динамическое-программирование, текстовые-файлы

Работаю над задачей по динамическому программированию.

Задача старая и из олимпиады:
На рисунке изображен треугольник из чисел. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет
наибольшую сумму чисел, расположенных на пути, начинающемся в верхней точке
треугольника и заканчивающемся на основании треугольника.

```
7
4 5
2 4 5
7 5 6 8
```

Каждый шаг на пути может осуществляться вниз по диагонали влево или вниз по
диагонали вправо. Количество строк и сам треугольник задаются с помощью текстового файла

Собственно код самой задачи у меня уже есть. Однако мне ещё нужно сделать вывод этого треугольника и отметить элементы этого треугольника по которым шла программа(либо цветом либо ещё как-то).

```
**7**
**3** 8
**8** 1 0
2 **7** 4 4
4 **5** 2 6 5
```

Каким образом мне выделить именно те элементы которые мне нужны, я понятия не имею. Поэтому прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.
Вот собственно код:

```
#include<iostream>

#include "fstream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int** a, N, i, j, ** b;
    ifstream file("1.txt");
    file >> N;
    cout << N << endl;
    a = new int* [N];
    b = new int* [N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[N];
        b[i] = new int[N];
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            b[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            file >> a[i][j];
    b[0][0] = a[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (b[i + 1][j] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j]) {
                b[i + 1][j] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j];
                cout << a[i + 1][j] << endl;
            }
            if (b[i + 1][j + 1] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1])
                b[i + 1][j + 1] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1];
        }
    int max = b[N - 1][0];
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        if (b[N - 1][i] > max)
            max = b[N - 1][i];
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    cout << "Max summ= " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

Заведите ещё один массив. Когда в if происходит обновление ячейки b[][], записывайте в соотв. ячейку c[][], откуда пришли - из левой или из правой верхней ячейки.

Когда работа закончена, с нижней строчки от максимума разматывайте до верха цепочку.

Для начала нужно найти индекс максимума

```
int imax = 0;
for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    if (b[N - 1][i] > b[N - 1][imax])
        imax = i;
```

Затем пройти по записанной в `c[][]` последовательности

```
for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
    a[i][imax] = - a[i][imax]; //пометили число минусом
    imax = c[i][imax];
}
```

Теперь осуществляем вывод по строкам в нормальном порядке, но если число отрицательное, выводим звёздочку, `-a[i][imax]`, звёздочку

Как вариант не портить a

```
for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
    t = imax;
    imax = c[i][imax];
    c[i][t] = -1; //пометили ячейку, при выводе проверяем c на это значение
}
```

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, но можете по подробней насчёт того что записывать c[][]. Элемент из b или номер элемента. Или что то другое?
И что имеется ввиду под разматыванием? Какой-то определённый способ вывода? Извиняюсь если слишком много вопросов, просто я совсем в этом деле новый.

Comment: Записывать то, по чему удобно вам восстановить путь - индекс верхнего элемента в строке. Разматывать - из `a[N-1][k]` перейти в `a[N-2][с[N-1][k]]`, потом на строчку выше и так далее

Comment: если я правильно понял записывается вот так `if (b[i + 1][j] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j]) {c[i][j] = j;b[i + 1][j] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j];`
Но с реализацией размотки косяк кажется проблема
`for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) { if (j = c[i][j]) { cout << a[N-i][c[N-i][j]] << " " } }`
как лучше его реализовать?

Comment: Раскрутка в обратном порядке идёт. Добавил набросок

Comment: Спасибо!!!!! Мне кажется  почти получилось ещё чуть чуть осталось, только не всегда отмечаются  те цифры которые нужны. Может с выводом что то не так?
`for (i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
 for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
 {
 if (a[i][j] < 0) {
 cout << "*" ;
a[i][j] = -a[i][j];
} cout << a[i][j] << " " }`

Comment: Да вроде всё верно. Можно не изменять знак в матрице, только для вывода  `{  if (a[i][j] < 0) { cout << "*" << -a[i][j] << " " }`. А при первом обходе вы в обоих ифах `с` заполняете?

Comment: если вы имеете в виду в if (b[i + 1][j] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j]), то да.  Именно в нём проблема? Я не то c присваиваю? Вот второй иф
`if (b[i + 1][j + 1] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1]) { b[i + 1][j + 1] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1];c[i][j] = j;}`

Comment: В комментариях трудно читать. Лучше отредактируйте вопрос, добавив текущую версию кода

Comment: Эээ, кажется, действительно не то. Вы же заполняете b[i + 1][j + 1], значит, и с[i + 1][j + 1],и в первом ифе индексы c должны соответствовать индексам b

Comment: ДА, ТЕПЕРЬ ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ. СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!!!